# How do I model a plant growing through a hard surface?

Tags: modeling

[image]I was struggling with modeling that bump (particularly sharp edges, cracks). What would be the best way to do that? Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: I think you might want to investigate some "explosion" tutorials.  IMHO, the plant is exploding through the surface in very slow motion.

Comment: is it supposed to be animated? You could even do it with texture instead of modelling...

Comment: Not animated. Just like a bump on the wooden floor in the corner there

Comment: Wooden floor reacts differently on pressure from underground than elastic asphalt ... Wood wouldn't be just a bump (•‿•)

Comment: Probably, but how do I model that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Wooden floor

You can start with addon [Floor Board Generator](https://github.com/importbpy/Floorboard-Generator) ...

[image]
Setup in "vintage" style ...

In edit mode select a few planks in place you want to crack the floor and *Separate* <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*.

Use **Annotate Pencil** from tool bar to draw a line (*On Surface*) and use a build-in addon **Cell Fracture** to crack those planks. Set *Point Source > Annotation Pencil* with some *Noise*.

[image]

[image]
Noise 0.1

[image]
Noise 0.001 (lower value = more spiky / straight shards).

Search for *Add Rigid Body > Active* with all shards selected. Than search for *Rigid Bodies *Connect* to add constraints between shards. In properties (left down corner of 3D view) select **Chain by Distance**.

[image]

Under *Physics Properties* (with all constraints selected and one *Active* -bright orange), enable **Breakable**. Hovering above checkbox, right-click and select *Copy to Selected*. Lower *Threshold* value (copy to others in the same way).

*Add Rigid Body > Passive* to other objects participating in simulation.
Green *Cone* is animated on Z axis (with option *Animated* enabled under *Physics Properties*).

[image]

Notes:

- [Nice tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErM_qJV5FwQ) about fracturing with Cell Fracture addon
- There also exists a build of experimental *Blender* with *Fracture Modifier*, that could handle this task in more efficient way (but on Mac is last version blender 2.8 ... and I could not find the Annotation Pencil feature).
- Sometimes addon "looses" some shards - it happens due boolean operation. If does it happen to you, enable in addon's popup window - *Debug Boolean* ... this will keep Boolean as modifiers. You can select origin of "invisible" object, and in modifier panel switch from *Exact* to **Fast**. Before assigning Rigid Body, I had to apply modifiers ... just select all shards and Search for *Convert to Mesh*.

---

### Asphalt surface

For "elastic" material like asphalt at your reference ... just model or sculpt a hump and use image texture with b&w crack as a factor to mix outer/inner materials ... or if you want more relief use this texture in Displace modifier too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much that is really helpful! However I can't get the planch addon to work in 3.0.1. Could you include a brief instruction on how to install it? I just installed  a .py file from the github, but there didn't appear any new tabs for me in Blender (and can't find it in the old ones like 'edit', 'tool' etc.)

Comment: See edit ... I used wrong link.